# How do I set the background of an xml on click in Android

Tags: android, setbackground

Here is what I want to do: I click on a button which opens and activity that changes the background periodically.

My code looks like this:

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picscreen);

Thread background = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            sleep(2000);

            relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img10); 
            setContentView(relativeLayout);

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
};
    background.start();
}protected void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
```

}

The error says the relative Layout cannot ba applied to a thread. What do I do wrong?

Comment: You have to use the main ui thread if you want to manipulate layouts and views. Also, you need to instantiate the RelativeLayout inside your onCreate. And use an OnClickEventListener if you want to do as you describe in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error says the relative Layout cannot ba applied to a thread

Because `run` method context is used for creating `RelativeLayout` layout object and calling `setContentView`

You should use `YourActivityName.this` instead of `this` for calling `setContentView` method and creating `RelativeLayout` layout object.

*Suggestion:*

When Application run with current code application will crash with following message:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

So use `runOnUiThread` or [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) (instead of Thread) for doing some task after specific time

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    //your code
});
```

in your run method and before this you will have to call looper.prepare() i think, but I have no idea why you are creating a new RealtiveLayout each time in run method, its pretty lame. You can use same RelativeLayout every time and then you will not have to call method setContentView().
I would suggest you take a good look at android basic tutorials.